# Check if merged cells are blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, merge, cells

I have an Excel 2003 spreadsheet containing a mix of UK date and currency formatted cells. I cannot change the structure of the spreadsheet. In VBA, during a worksheet change event, I want to check if the user has deleted the data from a number of ranges comprised of merged cells. I have tried IsNull and IsEmpty but they don't work on merged cells. Using Range.value = "" throws up an error.

In simplier terms;

If a change event occurs AND
the change involves a range comprised of merged cells AND
the change is a deletion of data from the merged cells 
Then
Exit Sub
Else
my existing code covers this...
End if

I've read forums far and wide for a simple solution but nothing yet does the trick. Grateful for any help. Thanks and keep up the great work!!

Answer (score 3):

When processing the `Change` event there are three scenarios you need to consider:

1. `Target` consists of `Unmerged` cells only
2. `Target` consists of a single `Merged` range only
3. `Target` consists of one or more `Merged` ranges plus zero or more `Unmerged` cells

The `Range.MergeCells` properties reveals these possibilities:

1. `Range.MergeCells = FALSE`
2. `Range.MergeCells = TRUE`
3. `Range.MergeCells = NULL`

When `Range.MergeCells = NULL` you will need to examine each cell in `Target` range individually to see which are merged

Something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cl As Range

    If IsNull(Target.MergeCells) Then
        'Changed Range contains one or more Merged cells and other cells
        For Each cl In Target.Cells
            If cl.MergeCells Then
                ' only consider top left cell of a merged range
                If cl.Address = cl.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Address Then
                    If cl = "" Then
                        MsgBox "Merged Cell Deleted " & cl.MergeArea.Address

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Else
        If Target.MergeCells Then
            ' Changed Range is a single Merged cells
            If Target.Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
                MsgBox "Merged Cell Deleted " & Target.Address

            End If
        Else
            'Changed Range is Unmerged cells only
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1, nicely explained and coded. I don't have to deal with merged cells often and always have to relearn the VBA. This it's very clear.